# Is it safe to give multiple virtual credit card numbers to the same vendor?

Tags: credit-card, banks

There are situations when I have to give several virtual credit card numbers linked to my real credit card to the same vendor. Can a vendor guess the real credit card number by having multiple virtual credit card numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> Can a vendor guess the real credit card number by having multiple virtual credit card numbers?

The answer is no.

By looking at your temporary numbers, they could determine which network and bank issued the card (from the BIN, the first 6 digits). But they would not be able to tell your various cards apart from any other cards issued for that product by that bank, and there would be no relationship discernible between the temporary cards and your real card based on knowing the card number(s) alone.